# Add library to laravel via composer

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container, tumblr

I have installed laravel via composer and Tumblr php library via composer as well. Now when I say:

```
var_dump(App::make('Tumblr'));
```

I get and exception that `Class Tumblr does not exist`. How should I make this class visible to laravel? I use laravel 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using this library (https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/), you will need to use namespaces or set an alias in the app.php config file.

Using namespaces:

```
$client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
$client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);
```

And you can set an alias in the alias array:

```
'Tumblr' => 'Tumblr\API\Client'

$tumblr = new Tumblr;
```

And if you wanna you the IoC container, you can set a bind:

```
App::bind('Tumblr', 'Tumblr\API\Client');

$tumblr = App::make('Tumblr');
```